# How to set a hotspot that proxify all connections with tor?

Tags: proxy, http-proxy, tor, wifi-hotspot

Say I am connected with  `eth0` to Internet and create a hotspot with:

```
create_ap wlan0 eth0 MyAccessPoint MyPassPhrase
```

How to set the machine that generate the hotspot to proxify all connections through tor (i.e altering all packets arriving at wlan0 in the same fashion as `proxychains` does for a specific application).

Comment: I think you just need to set the route for traffic from that device to go though TOR

Comment: eth0 connects to what?  internet router?

Comment: Tor is for TCP connections...http://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/4523/can-i-use-tor-through-udp-protocol/4524#4524

Comment: @jasen which tools or precise command would you use. I am unexperimented.

Comment: if I knew the details I'd have posted an answer, not a comment.

Answer (score 0):

[This post](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/12265/how-can-i-bridge-wlan-to-ethernet-through-tor/12266#12266) proposes a [script](https://github.com/grugq/PORTALofPi/blob/master/build.sh) that bridge wifi to  ethernet by force everything to go through tor.

It is designed for *Archlinux* (`pacman` should be replaced with `apt-get`, etc.)